# Display the most recent commit of each branch in git

Tags: git

Is there a way to display the most recent commits of each branch in git?

I have a codebase in git that I've set down for a while. There are several branches in it for different features. I need to go in and update/troubleshoot some code However I choose to name them too generically and now I can't tell which one I was working on last, or even which one had my feature in it.

Ideally I would like to see the last commit in each branch to get an overview of where I last left things. Is there a command to do this? I just need to see where I was working last. I want to avoid switching to each branch and looking at its log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git show <name_of_the_branch>`

will display the most recent commit for the branch `<name_of_the_branch>`

Answer (score 5):

```
git branch -v
```

will display the (short form of) the most recent commit's SHA1 in its second column and the description after that.